# Can I create an object for a class from an imported package

Tags: java

I am a beginner at java.

I have imported a package in the code and want to use the functions from the imported class. It says object cannot be resolved.

The code is as follows

```
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.WeightedQuickUnionUF;

public class Percolation {
  private int[] full;
  private int length;
  private int size;

  public Percolation(int n) {              
    length = n + 2;
    WeightedQuickUnionUF uf = new WeightedQuickUnionUF(length);

  }

  // Now if I use the uf object in another function as below

  public boolean isFull(int i, int j) {
    boolean result = false;
    if(uf.connected(0,i+j)) {
      result = true;
    }
    return result;
  }
}

//uf.connected in the public function declared in WeightedQuickUnionUF package.
//Its definition is as follows
public boolean connected(int p, int q) { /* ... */ }
```

It gives me an error

```
Error: uf cannot be resolved
```

`uf.connected` in the public function declared in `WeightedQuickUnionUF` package.
Its definition is as follows

```
public boolean connected(int p, int q) { /* ... */ }
```

Please advice how to access the function from the imported package.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is outside of the class

Comment: well, yeah. You created `uf` in the constructor only. It's discarded right afterwards. If you want to have access to it in the entire class you need to make it a (private) variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created the variable uf inside the constructor, and it means the other functions will not be able to see it/use it.

As someone already said above, you can either, for example, create the WeightedQuickUnionUF object inside isFull() function, or, since you want the length and you receive it as a parameter in the constructor do something like:

```
//now uf is a local variable inside a Percolation object
private WeightedQuickUnionUF uf;

public Percolation(int n) {              
    length = n + 2;
    //now uf is created whenever you create a Percolation object
    uf = new WeightedQuickUnionUF(length);
}
```

Now you can access it in isFull() method!

Answer (score 2):

You have created local variable `uf` into constructor and try to access it from method `isFull()`.

You can either:

1. Create object `uf` into method `isFull()` and use it
2. make `uf` a member of your class and use it.
3. use call method of `uf` from constructor.

Answer (score 1):

This is a context problem: `uf` is declared in Percolation's constructor, and is not an attribute of the class.